# Коси, Косой, косой косой

Tags: орфоэпия

Является ли этот призыв к человеку с прозвищем "Косой" косить с помощью косой косы тавтологией?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотря как определять тавтологию.
Риторы и лингвисты широкого профиля определяют тавтологию как разновидность плеоназма:  употребление в предложении однокоренных слов с целью повышения выразительности фразы. В этом смысле указанное предложение - тавтология.

Стилисты же под тавтологией чаще понимают лексическую ошибку, связанную с подобным употреблением. Поскольку лексической ошибки нет (наоборот - очень выразительно), то и тавтологии в этом смысле тут нет.

Answer (score 7):

Нет, это не тавтология. Это, я думаю,  КАЛАМБУР.

КАЛАМБУ́Р, каламбура, муж. (франц. calembour). Игра слов, использование разных значений одного и того же слова (или двух сходно звучащих слов) с целью произвести комическое впечатление.
*dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ушакова*

КАЛАМБУ́Р, а, м. [фр. calembour].Шутка, основанная на комическом использовании сходно звучащих, но разных по значению слов.Каламбури́ст —любитель говорить каламбурами.Каламбу́рный —являющийся, характеризующийся каламбуром.Каламбу́рить —говорить каламбурами.|К. нередко используется для создания каламбурных рифм, напр.: "Область рифм — моя стихия, И легко пишу стихи я" (Д. Минаев).
*Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004*

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что формально не являются, но, конечно, это предложение ни чем иным, как курьезом, быть не может)))

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут есть аналогичные [англоязычные примеры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)